# Splitting Data Into Training and Test set

Tags: classification

I am trying to split a data set into training and test set with these codes

```
   table (A)
       A
    No   Yes 

  21343  4419 

  set.seed(88)  
  split <- sample.split(mydata$A, SplitRatio = 0.75)  
  train <- subset(mydata, split == TRUE)  
  test <- subset(mydata, split == FALSE)
  table(train$A)

   No   Yes 
 16007  3314 
>table(test$A)

   No  Yes 
  5336 1105
```

i want to ask that is there any way to get equal number of responses in training or test set??
that is, for training set number of responses for YES and NO will be 3314 ??